# Windows Server 2008 Resource Monitor - Memory - What do the different columns mean?

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory

When I click on Resource Monitor in the Task Manager on my Windows Server 2008 machine, I see a few sections. When I click on memory, I see a few columns defining types of memory.

Commit, Working Set, and Private

For example, for MySQL Server...

Commit = 191MB, Working Set = 33MB, and Private = 28MB.

What do these mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170654/how-to-interpret-windows-task-manager/1170741#1170741)

[Working set](http://blogs.msdn.com/salvapatuel/archive/2007/10/13/memory-working-set-explored.aspx):

Working set is the subset of virtual pages that are resident in physical memory only; this will be a partial amount of pages from that process.

[Private working set](http://cybernetnews.com/cybernotes-windows-memory-usage-explained/):

The private working set is the amount of memory used by a process that cannot be shared among other processes

[Commit size](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-us/help/d119bbe6-f604-4eb1-9c75-bbbc45cce1da1033.mspx):

Amount of [virtual memory](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-US/Help/fd3e9104-1076-4600-9f9d-8739849387ec1033.mspx) that is reserved for use by a process.

And at [microsoft.com](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-us/help/d119bbe6-f604-4eb1-9c75-bbbc45cce1da1033.mspx) you can find more details about other memory types.